# How do keep all my inbox received emails on my Galaxy 3

Tags: email

When sychronising, all the emails i moved to archive on my pc disappear from my Galaxy S3 inbox. I had a Blackberry previously and it would retain all emails received for a set period, 4 weeks in my case, regardless of what i did on the pc. Is there anyway to set the Galaxy S3 to retain all incoming emails ?

Comment: Sure, but first you should tell use which e-mail app and which e-mail provider you use.

Comment: -1 ,you should provide the app and the e-mail provider

Comment: Please also specify: What protocol do you use (IMAP or POP3)? This information is useful in addition to what Flow kindly requested.

Answer (score 1):

Reading it again: The way you speak of synchronizing, you probably use IMAP. So if you move mails out of one folder on one client, this gets synced to the other clients as well.

If the archive is a local folder, you will thus not find them on your S3 anymore (as for this client, the mails simply got "deleted"). But if it's a subfolder on the IMAP server, you simply need to locate this folder on your SGS3. How this is done, depends on the client used -- so we cannot tell you unless you specify those details requested in the comments.